# Is the "blue" in "blue moon" a reference to betrayal?

Tags: etymology, phrases, old-english

There are some previous questions on this site about the etymology of the phrase "blue moon" ([What is the origin of the phrase "blue moon"? Any alternate phrase for it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8877/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-blue-moon-any-alternate-phrase-for-i), [Why do we call some full moons "blue" when they're not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43702/why-do-we-call-some-full-moons-blue-when-theyre-not)). But none of these posts deals with a surprising hypothesis currently mentioned on the Wikipedia article "[Blue Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon#Origin_of_the_term)": that the word "blue" here is somehow connected to the Old English verb *[belǽwan](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/003569)* meaning "to betray":

> The suggestion has been made that the term "blue moon" for "intercalary month" arose by folk etymology, the "blue" replacing the no-longer-understood belewe, 'to betray'. The original meaning would then have been "betrayer moon", referring to a full moon that would "normally" (in years without an intercalary month) be the full moon of spring, while in an intercalary year, it was "traitorous" in the sense that people would have had to continue fasting for another month in accordance with the season of Lent.

As far as I can tell, none of the references listed in the Wikipedia article seems to be a reliable source for etymological information, or to reference any more reliable source to back up this etymology.

The first linked reference is an article "[What is a Blue Moon](https://www.farmersalmanac.com/what-is-a-blue-moon-2404)" by the staff of Farmers' Almanac that simply says

> One explanation connects it with the word *belewe* from the Old English, meaning, “to betray.” Perhaps, then, the Moon was “belewe” because it betrayed the usual perception of one full Moon per month.

(Note the vague wording here—"One explanation connects it with"—as in the  Wikipedia article—"The suggestion has been made").

Neither the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), nor the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blue%20moon) provide any support for the idea that the term "blue moon" has any connection to Old English *belǽwan* "to betray". To the contrary, the OED indicates that the "blue" in "blue moon" is derived from the familar color word, which is a loanword from French (although French in turn got the word from a Germanic language). The OED does indicate that the color word *blue* was spelled "belewe" in some Middle English manuscript or manuscripts.

Does anyone know of any more scholarly etymological sources than the ones that Wikipedia references that discuss this hypothesis?

Comment: In the Western tradition, Lent is backdated 40 days, not counting Sundays, from Easter Sunday, which falls on the first Sunday after the first full moon after the vernal equinox. There could never be an "extra" month of fasting.

Comment: Wikrapedia strikes again.

Comment: @KarlG ebareis posts: << Correction: "Easter Sunday, which falls on the first Sunday after the first "new moon" (not "full moon") after the vernal equinox." >>

Comment: The new moon has nothing to do with the Christian dating of Easter and only marginally with setting the Passover month of Nissan, with Passover falling on 14 Nissan. The equinoctal rule was finally set at the Council of Nicaea.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not super interested in how the date of Easter is calculated, so I might be wrong, but my impression after glancing at the relevant Wikipedia article is that ebareis is incorrect.

Comment: Jon Rogers, in the [Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/8836859/easter-2020-when-date-holiday-good-friday/), says: 'Because the precise timing of observing the full moon can vary in each time zone, the Church instead calculates the date from ecclesiastical calendar. This divides 19 normal calendar years into 235 months of 30 and 29 days each, with the ecclesiastical full moon on the 14th day of each lunar month. The "paschal full moon" – from the Aramaic for Passover – is the one that falls on or after the spring equinox on March 21. Easter Day is the first Sunday after the paschal full moon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between "blue" and "betrayer" in describing the periodic extra (thirteenth) moon in one of every three (more exactly 2.7) solar years is based on folklore and is therefore poor in documentation. It appears to be a pun and/or a case of false friends, and it's unclear how old or recent their connection is.

**On the historical spellings of "blue" and "betrayer":**

The modern English word "blue" has seen various spellings, including:

- "blwe" (c 1300), from the [*Online Etymology Dictionary*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blue).
- "blewe" (c 1150–1580), from [*A Concise Dictionary of Middle-English*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/10625/10625-h/dict1.html#word_blewe_adj) (by Mayhew & Skeat, Oxford).

The modern English word "betrayer" is a cognate of the verb "to betray".

- The infinitive was at one time in Old English spelled "belæwan" (c 5th–12th century), per the [*Old English Translator*](https://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/) (compiled by a hobbyist).
- The first-person singular spelling of Old English "betray" is given above as "belæwe". This spelling matches "belewe", save for the Æ in place of the second E. Note that Æ has evolved into AE and then often simply to E in many English words.

From the above history, and knowing the non-standard history of pre-Modern English, one can see there was overlap in similar spellings of "blue" and "betray", despite their ultimate derivations being from two different PIE roots, allowing for the possibility of false-friend association and puns.

**On the oft-claimed connecting word, "belewe"**:

The antiquated and obscure word "belewe" if often cited as a bridge between the terms "blue" and "betrayer":

- [*Intat.net*](https://www.intat.net/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-almanac/) (1993-12-03): "The *blue moon* was originally defined by the Maine Farmers' Almanac as the third full moon in… [Ellipses here are from the source, and no further content or citation is given there.] Some have posited that the name comes from the Old English word *belewe*, meaning *to betray*, because the *blue* moon *betrays* the usual one full moon per…"
- [Unity Churchill Nursery](http://www.unitychurchhillnursery.com/event/blue-moon-2/) (1999-03-15): "In calculating the dates for Lent and Easter, the Clergy identify the Lent moon. It is thought that historically when the moon's timing was too early, they named an earlier moon as a *betrayer moon* (*belewe moon*), thus the Lent moon came at its expected time. Folklore gave each moon a name according to its time of year. A moon that came too early had no folk name, and was called a *blue* moon, retaining the correct seasonal timings for future moons."
- Peter Geiger, [*Farmers' Almanac 2001*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ywxNfmwZOU8C&dq=belewe+betray+blue+moon&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=betray) (2000-09-01): "[The beginning of this sentence is not visible in Google Books' preview] …meaning, *to betray*. Perhaps, then, the moon was *belewe* because it *betrayed* the usual perception of one full moon per month."
- Joe Rao, [*Curso Objectivo*](http://www.curso-objetivo.br/vestibular/resolucao_comentada/fgvsp/2003_2_1fase/FGVSP2003_2_1fase.pdf) (2003-02-01): "One likely explanation has to do with the Old English word *belewe*, meaning *to betray*. The moon, this theory states, is *belewe* because it *betrays* the usual perception of one full moon per month."
- Joe Rao, [*Space.com* via *NBC News*](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/5351800/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/science-history-behind-blue-moon/#.Wq7WnJPwYsk) (2004-07-02): "The phrase 'once in a *blue* moon' was first noted in **1824** and refers to occurrences that are uncommon, perhaps even rare. … I myself once [no date or source given as to when or where exactly he means at this writing, though note he's the author of the previous quotation from a year prior] suggested that the rule might have evolved out of the fact that the word *belewe* came from the Old English, meaning, *to betray*. 'Perhaps,' I suggested, 'the second full moon is *belewe* because it *betrays* the usual perception of one full moon per month.'"
- Greg Alexander, [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Blue_moon&oldid=189214101) (2008-02-05): "An alternative interpretation uses the other meaning of *belewe* (which can mean *blue* or *betrayer*)[citation here to the *Farmers' Almanac* website, but no quotation]. The Church was responsible for calculating … the date of Easter … the first Sunday after the [first] full moon [following spring equinox] (the egg moon). The preceding moon (Lent moon …) is also an important Christian time. In years where the Lent or egg moon would [appear] too early, the moon was a *betrayer* moon, [it] was not to be used to [commemorate] the death and resurrection of Christ. Thus the clergy would tell the people that it was not the Lent moon they were seeing, but a false moon—a *betrayer* moon."
- Farmers' Almanac Staff, [*Farmers' Almanac*](https://www.farmersalmanac.com/what-is-a-blue-moon-2404) (2009-08-24): "One explanation [no citation given] connects it with the word *belewe* from Old English, meaning *to betray*. Perhaps, then, the moon was *belewe* because it *betrayed* the usual perception of one full moon per month."
- [*Buffalo Sunday News*](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~insrisg/nature/nw10/0110BlueMoon.htm) (2010-01-10): "Apparently the astronomical use of *blue moon* derives not from a color but from an earlier word, *belewe*, meaning *betrayer*. The calculation of the date of Easter and the associated Lenten period is determined by lunar cycles. In some years a reasonable date for this religious feast did not satisfy the clergy because of an extra seasonal full moon, so that moon was rejected as a *betrayer*—a *belewe* moon."
- Dave Tabler, [*Appalachian History*](http://www.appalachianhistory.net/2013/01/happy-new-year.html) (2013-01-01): "…one explanation connects it with the word *belewe* from Old English, meaning *to betray*. Perhaps, then, the moon was *belewe* because it *betrayed* the usual perception of one full moon per month. 'Yf they saye the mone is *belewe*, We must beleve that it is true,' says William Barlow, the Bishop of Chichester, in the *Treatyse of the Buryall of the Masse*, **1528**. There are twelve full moons in most years, which means that three full moons occur during most seasons. One season in ten contains four full moons; hence the third moon that occurs in such a season would be the *belewe*, or *blue*, moon."
- Husna Haq, [*Christian Science Monitor*](https://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2015/0729/Blue-moon-What-is-a-blue-moon-and-where-can-you-see-it) (2015-07-29): "Some [cited with a broken link] have posited that the name comes from the Old English word *belewe*, meaning *to betray*, because the *blue* moon *betrays* the usual one full moon per month norm, by which farmers once marked the changing of seasons."
- Jon Austin, [*Sunday Express*](https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/595237/RARE-BLUE-SUPER-MOON-Top-5-facts) (2015-07-31): "…some [no citation] suggest the term *blue* refers to a *betrayer moon* from *belewe* in Old English."
- Gordon Johnston, [*NASA Science*](https://moon.nasa.gov/news/40/moon-missive-the-next-full-moon-is-a-super-blue-blood-moon-the-snow-moon-or-the-hunger-moon/) (2018-01-29): "Originally, the term *blue moon* referred to the third full moon in a season that has four full Moons. The earliest known reference to a *blue moon* in the English language is the phrase '…the mone is *blewe*…' from a pamphlet published in **1528**. Some writers [no citation in source at to who] speculate that *blue* came from *belewe*, the phrase meant *betrayer moon*, and that the name referred to how an extra moon in a season confused or *betrayed* the dates for Lent and Easter. The newer definition of a *blue moon* as the second full moon in a calendar month dates from **1946**."
- Jeff Parsons, [*Mirror*](https://www.mirror.co.uk/science/where-see-blue-blood-moon-11758448) (2018-02-01): "Normally, a year would have 12 moons, but when a moon appears for the 13th time—an unusual occurrence—it was referred to as a *belewe* moon, which means *betrayer*. The earliest English language reference is thought to be found in an anti-clerical pamphlet written in **1528**."

From the above quotations, it's unclear whether Joe Rao originated the blue–belewe–betrayer connection, whether a different modern author drew this conclusion for Mr Rao and others to perpetuate, or whether the connection is indeed pre-modern.

Comment: As KarlG says, there’s no room for “extra” fasting. What if Easter maths is the other way round; a “traitor” moon leads the faithful to finish fasting early… an extra moon signals either a false end or even an early start to the fast? The Easter point, after all, is not X days of fasting, but *which* days.
Else, what have “betrayal” or “traitor” to do with agriculture, please? “False” might describe an extra moon but kills any phonetic link. Jiggling back and forth, isn’t it true that primitive farmers depend on the moon, not a written calendar and certainly not a completed religious almanac?

Comment: The lunar month is ~29.5 days. Most solar years see 12 full moons, but 29.5 x 12 is ~11.25 days short of ~365.25 days. If your lunar year always counts 12 moons (no leap moon), in a few years, you plant crops early according to solar seasons. The medieval new year was calibrated at spring equinox (Easter), and was preceded by fasting (Lent). An unexpected 13th moon before equinox could bring an extended fast. When the pattern was recognized, a leap moon was introduced.

Comment: May I ask please why the downvote?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful links. One thing that I also found helpful was to look at the dates of all of the relevant articles. The Buffalo Sunday News  (January 10, 2010), NASA Science  (January 29, 2018), The Atlantic (December 31, 2009), UK Mirror (1 FEB 2018), UK Express (Jul 31, 2015), and Christian Science Monitor (JULY 29, 2015) articles were all published after the Wikipedia article was edited to include this hypothesis about the etymology (on 5 February 2008, by an editor who cited the Farmers' Almanac article). So I think it is likely that they learned about this idea from Wikipedia.

Comment: The NBC News article comes before the Wikipedia article, in 2004, and in fact the author, Joe Rao, seems to say there that he was the initial person to propose this etymology: "For the longest time, no one seemed to have a clue as to where the “Blue Moon Rule” originated.  I myself once suggested that the rule might have evolved out of the fact that the word “belewe” came from the Old English, meaning, “to betray.”  “Perhaps,” I suggested, “the second full moon is ‘belewe’ because it betrays the usual perception of one full moon per month.”"

Comment: @jtheletter: no medieval calendar in the West was lunar except the Jewish religious calendar. The celebration of Easter was regulated at the Council of Nicaea in 325 to the Alexandrine rule of Sunday after the first full moon after the vernal equinox. It is a lunar date because of Ex 12. No other full moon mattered to the Church. And again, there is no possibility of an "extended fast." The New Year in the Middle Ages: some followed the so-called Annunciation style where the year began on 25 March. Others had other dates.

Comment: The Gregorian and Julian calendars are solar. The calculation of Lent and Easter is lunar. The traditional dates for farming (when to sow, reap, etc) are lunar. The Church held authority on astronomical record-keeping, by virtue of capital wealth and literacy.

Comment: @jtheletter: Again, the only moon that counts is the one after the equinox. There  is no such thing as a "Lenten" moon.

Comment: No such thing? Google reports thousands of results for "Lenten moon", including NASA, Farmers' Almanac, EarthSky, and published books.

Comment: Sorry to bore anyone and could we get back on track? Look at the OQ; its details might be inextricably linked to the date of Easter and the dating of Easter has caused endless controversy in church circles but could we get to blue moons and treachery, please?

Answer (score 3):

**Blue moon** is first recorded in the very early 18th century, and was quite literal and, unsurprisingly, it continues in the present:

> **1702–A moon (real, depicted, or imagined) that appears blue.** On rare occasions the moon can appear distinctly blue owing to the
> presence of smoke or dust particles in the atmosphere.
>
> 1702 *This exactly resembles our English Brimstone Butterfly..were it
> not for those black Spots, and apparent blue Moons in the lower
> Wings.* J. Petiver, Gazophylacii vol. I. 16
>
> 1883 *The red sun and the blue moon mean higher temperature and
> general rain.* Science 24 August 252/1
>
> 1987 *If a blue moon sat in the empty sky..would I regret knowing that
> its source was a rare rising of forest fire dust?* BOMB Spring 74

Obviously, blue moons were not common and thus a figurative meaning arose:

> **2.a. colloquial. A long or indefinite length of time; a rarely recurring period or event.**
>
> 1821 *‘How's Harry and Ben?—haven't seen you this blue moon.’ [Note]
> Blue Moon—This is usually intended to imply a long time.* P. Egan,
> Real Life in London vol. I. xiv. 24

That there is a note would imply that the phrase was not well-known at that time.

That said, a short time later:

> **2.b. once in a blue moon: rarely, exceptionally. Cf. once in a moon at once** adv., conj., adj., & n. Phrases P.4.
>
> 1833 *We are no advocates for the eternal system of producing foreign
> operas to the exclusion of the works of English composers, but once in
> a blue moon such a thing may be allowed.* Athenæum 16 November 780/1

It was not until the 1930s that the second moon in a calendar month got a name – and even then it was a specific “blue moon”

The “Farmer’s Almanac version appeared in 1937

> **3. Originally U.S. Originally: the third full moon in a season which (exceptionally) contains four full moons (each season, as defined by
> the mean sun, normally containing three full moons) (now historical).
> In later use: a second full moon in a calendar month.**
>
> As shown in Sky & Telescope (1999) May 36–8, the later use of the term
> originated in a misunderstanding of the source of quot. 1937 by the
> author of quot. 1946.
>
> A blue moon in the original Maine Farmers' Almanac sense can only
> occur in the months of February, May, August, and November. In the
> later sense, (i.e. two in one calendar month) one can occur in any
> month except February. This later sense gained currency from its use
> in a United States radio programme, StarDate, in 1980, and its
> inclusion in the game Trivial Pursuit in 1986.
>
> Earlier occurrences of the sense given in the Maine Farmers' Almanac
> have not been traced, either in editions of the Almanac prior to 1937,
> or elsewhere; the source of this application of the term (if it is not
> a coinage by the editor, H. P. Trefethen) is unclear.
>
> 1937 *This extra moon had a way of coming in each of the seasons so that it could not be given a name appropriate to the time of year like the other moons. It was usually called the Blue Moon. There are seven Blue Moons in a Lunar Cycle of nineteen years.* Maine Farmers' Almanac August 21/2
>
> 1946 Dr. L. J. Lafleur quotes an explanation found in the Maine
> Farmers' Almanac for 1937... Full moons of the year were given
> names..provided there was only one per month. These names were as
> follows: Moon after Yule, Wolf Moon, Lenten Moon, [etc.]... But seven
> times in 19 years there were—and still are—13 full moons in a year.
> This gives 11 months with one full moon each and one with two. This
> second in a month, so I interpret it, was called Blue Moon.

At this stage we can confidently say that the idea of a long obsolete Old English verb (whose meaning seems to have no relation to the Moon or tradition) lying dormant for seven or eight centuries suddenly, in the 1930s, being linked to the second moon of a calendar month is nil.

Comment: The 1702 quote seems quite telling - it directly links "on rare occasions" to the colour blue, in a way that fits the idiom *much better* than something which recurs reliably every two to three years. The real mystery seems to be where the "extra moon in a season" sense came from - perhaps actually adapted *from* the idiom, by someone looking for a nice name?

Answer (score -1):

To me the numbers eleven and twelve are the key after all, with the core "leven" meaning left(over) in counting on one's fingers after ten: one left, two left.
https://taalaandewandel.com/2021/02/13/waarom-elf-en-niet-eentien/

In Dutch the word "blijven" (Eng.: remain) goes back to "be-lijven", with Germanic origin. In the 13th century found as "bliuen". That comes close to blue and belewe. It has the same core lijven/leven/left.  So the blue moon is the full moon that remains, is left over, after the twelfth. Or in a season after the third.
See: https://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/blijven

Actually I found it in English etymology as well:

Blive, belive:
From Middle English beliven, from Old English belīfan (“to remain”), from Proto-West Germanic *bilīban, from Proto-Germanic *bilībaną (“to remain”), from Proto-Germanic *bi- + Proto-Indo-European *leyp- (“to stick, glue”).

Cognate with West Frisian bliuwe (“to stay”), Dutch blijven (“to remain”), German bleiben (“to remain”), Danish blive (“to be, remain”). More at leave.
Alternative forms

```
bilive, blive
bleve, bileve, bilave, blewe
```

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belive#English

Blewe is actually also an obsolete form of blue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is all very speculative. It's often easy to come up with multiple *plausible* etymologies for a word, but finding out which is true requires finding historical evidence, not just comparing surface features of words.

Comment: As far as I know there is no definitive proof for the origin of "blue moon". So anything that has been written to suggest or propose a solution is speculation. Including this whole page. And then the similarities are in my opinion not "surface features". That a word for blue could be mistaken or used as pun for a word meaning remain or left over is well supported by the added links. I think they are substantial enough to make it for a "possible solution".

Comment: Yes indeed; but in that case the only answer we can give with any authority is that we don't know - and, as other answers have, present what direct clues we do have. Otherwise, it's just a game of looking through dictionaries until you find a word with roughly the right letters and telling a Just So story about how it connects.

Comment: Note that Greybeard's conclusion, if you accept it, would apply equally to this theory as it does to the one in the question: "At this stage we can confidently say that the idea of a long obsolete Old English verb (whose meaning seems to have no relation to the Moon or tradition) lying dormant for seven or eight centuries suddenly, in the 1930s, being linked to the second moon of a calendar month is nil."

Comment: What's the use of discussing etymologies that are not definitively proven correct, when any well researched suggestion or proposal is voted down because it were mere speculation? Which it is any way by definition. And you don't give any argument why it can't be right.
And otherwise: what's the use of discussing etymologies that are definitively proven correct?
In other words - what are we doing here?
Science would be nowhere without speculating - I would rather say postulating - and then trying to prove it with the help of others. E.g. in a discussion here....

Comment: If you're not familiar with the site format, it might be worth taking the [tour] - the idea is to discourage open-ended discussions, and instead have each answer stand alone, putting together the best evidence we *do* have, rather than throwing it ideas for someone else to run with. Perhaps there's a different site somewhere that would be more suitable to this "brainstorming" approach.

Comment: As for the theory itself, there's a few gaps: another answer suggests the evidence for an ancient calendar meaning is lacking, so the connection to "remainder" may be irrelevant; you need a participle not an infinitive (a "left over moon", not a "to leave over moon"); and the spelling "blewe" was presumably still rhymed with "live" or "leave", so you need to postulate some lost *writing* that was misread.

Comment: Analogous to give, given, a given value, there could be blive, bliven, a bliven moon.  Meaning a left(over) moon. The full moon that remains in a season after the three common full moons have appeared under their fixed seasonal names.

Consider the variations in blive-bliven, blijven-(ge)bleven (Dutch), bleiben-geblieben (German), bliuwe-bleaun (Frisian),...

There might have been a time and place when that came close to what was used for "blue". And yes that is speculation. But in my opinion not as far fetched as relating it to a verb meaning to betray.

Answer (score -3):

> the term "blue moon" for "intercalary month" arose by folk etymology,

> the "blue" replacing the no-longer-understood belewe, 'to betray'.

I shouldn't consider myself a scholarly source of course, but it is so glaringly obvious so that it might go as common sense knowledge.

If *eleven, twelve* contained as is usually thought an element *leven, left* (en.WT: [eleven](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eleven)) and if the intercalary month was precisely those days that were left at the end of a period in calendar (see below), then "belewe" cannot be anything but related to this idiom. *be-* may be the common prefix. *Moon* is related to *month*. This is *surface analysis*.

It's conceivable that a sense "left" could also come to mean desertion, betrayal, though I do disagree with the *-leven* theory of *eleven, twelve*, because it seems literally backwards, counting down – looking forward it requires a sense of "extra" rather than "left".

There is a lot to say about superstition in numerology and religion.

1. So Judas, one of the twelve apostle often painted as the twelfth in order, is the prototype of a betrayer. However, the unlucky number usually associated with this is thirteen and the origin of this superstition is not clear. For example:

> A year with 13 full moons instead of 12 posed problems for the monks in charge of the calendars. "This was considered a very unfortunate circumstance, especially by the monks who had charge of the calendar of thirteen months for that year, and it upset the regular arrangement of church festivals. For this reason, thirteen came to be considered an unlucky number."[23]

> [en.WP: [Thirteen (number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13_(number))]

2. It is notable that time keeping was not an exact science. The two-faced Roman god Janus gave it's name to *January*, technically the eleventh after *December* (*decem-* "10") with New Year's occasionally in March. The year "consisted of ten months, beginning in spring with March and leaving winter as an unassigned span of days before the next year" (en.WP: [January](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January)), "Plutarch's Parallel Lives recounts that Romulus's calendar had been solar but adhered to the general principle that the year should last for 360 days. Months were employed secondarily and haphazardly, with some counted as 20 days and others as 35 or more." "According to Livy, it was Numa Pompilius, the second king of Rome (715–673 BC), who divided the year into twelve lunar months (History of Rome, I.19)." (en.WP: [Roman Calender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_calendar))

It is notable, therefore, that Latin *liba* is a potential epithet of Janus, "which remains purely hypothetical." (en.WP: [Janus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Janus)), sacrifical cake, cp. λιπάω, *libate*.

> Une des épithètes de Janus est dérivée de l'offrande qu'on lui présentait le plus souvent. Lydus raconte que Yarron, dans le quatorzième livre *Rerum divinârum* mentionnait cette épithète, et il la traduit par Ποπάνων. ***Je pense que la forme latine aura été **Libo**.*** Il était d'usage de présenter au dieu des *liba* (πόπανα) les jours des calendes.

> [J. S. Speÿer, "Le dieu romain Janus", *Revue de l'histoire des religions* 26 (1892): 28; emphasis mine, @vectory]

Note also "the Saxon term *Wulf-monath* (meaning "wolf month")" (en.WT: [January](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January)) corresponds approximately to Dutch Low Saxon *elf*, German Low German *elf, eleve, ölve, ölven*, Old Saxon *ellevan* (en.WT: PGem. [**ainalif*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/ainalif) "eleven") and English *one* /w-/. Janus and January were sometimes equated with goddess *Juno* or *IUNO*, whose name is possibly cognate to Proto-West-Germanic **aiw-*, it may still be difficult to connect the forms of Old Saxon *ēo, ēu, ē* and Old High German *ēo*, but there is no good reason either to think of a wolf month. Compare *eve*, "with a pre-1200 loss of the terminal '-n'" (en.WT) or rather *advent*, *aventura*. So, *leave* can be associated with hollidays, cp. German *Urlaub*.

3. On another note, *leap year* is "Probably from a much older formation related to the Old Norse *hlaup-ár* (“leap year”), Old English *mōnan hlȳp* (“moon's leap”) (compare Latin *saltus lunae* used in reckoning lunar months on a 19-year cycle)." (en.WT: [leap year](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leap_year))

> The chief competitor of the system which Dionysius introduced into the West was that constructed in the fifth century by Victorius of Aquitaine, which held its ground in Gaul for nearly three hundred years. Both were based on the lunar cycle of nineteen years, but they differed in four points: the earliest permissible date of the vernal new moon, the earliest day after this on which Easter could be kept, the latest day on which Easter could fall, and the place in each cycle in which the lunar year should be shortened by one day (the *saltus lunae*).

> [Poole, Reginald L. “The Earliest Use of the Easter Cycle of Dionysius.” *The English Historical Review* 33, no. 129 (1918): 57.]

Note that *saltus lunae* is Medieval not Classical Latin (etymonline: [leap year](https://www.etymonline.com/word/leap%20year)) so it does not constitute independent evidence for *leap year*, inasmuch as a *folk etymology* is always subject to interpretation, because: "There was considerable confusion about dates and the systems upon which bishops, abbots, and secular courts depended in the eighth and ninth centuries, and it was a problem to say which calendar applied to any event, or just how it applied." (Stevens, Wesley M. *Speculum* 78, no. 1 (2003): 144) With German *Schaltjahr* ("leap year") in mind, we can safely identify *saltus* as a corrupted form of *kalendae* / *calendae*, cp. *yell*, see also *shall* and the irregular change of German *sollen*.

4. L. *linquo* "leave" compares better to *left (hand side)* than *levis*, *light*, cp. *sinister* and *sine* (if you dpn't know what this means you can safely ignore it and head on over to etymonline).

---

en.WP: [Twelve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_(number)) with one reference to OED ed. 1 and one reference to IEW **-lif*, **lib*

Comment: This is all just speculative, and not "obvious" at all. It's often easy to come up with multiple *plausible* etymologies for a word, but finding out which is true requires finding historical evidence, not just comparing surface features of words.

Comment: Surely the "comparative method" would be to identify words with the *same* meaning in other languages, and then see what they had in common, not to compare it to other words with similar *features*, then guess at a connection in meaning. For example, a surface reading makes "flutter by" -> "butterfly" seem quite plausible, but [an actual comparison among languages suggests it really is "butter" + "fly"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/55606/26673). Even if "belew" meaning either "betrayer" or "left" was still used, the connection to "blue moon" would be just as speculative as "flutterby".

Comment: @IMSoP that's a completely irrelevant point, unless you are low key suggesting *fly* was related to *leave*. If you are saying that *"blijven* (Eng.: remain) is not "the *same* meaning" required in naming the reminder of a calculation the problem is clearly on your end.

Comment: It was an example of how similarities that are "glaringly obvious" are as likely to lead to completely wrong folk etymologies as they are to lead to useful insight. It seems "glaringly obvious" that butterflies have nothing to do with butter, so we need to look elsewhere - but it turns out they *do*. In the same way, you may think it's "glaringly obvious" that the "blue" in "blue moon" is a corruption of a word for "remainder", but it's just as likely that it is complete coincidence, and maybe always was just the colour.

Comment: *"... it's just as likely that it is complete coincidence, and maybe always was just the colour."* Haven't I said that "I do in fact disagree with the -leven theory"? Etymologists hate this trick!

Comment: One more time, in case you're serious about missing my point: I am not making any connection whatever between "butter" or "butterfly" and "blue moon"; it is simply an example of being led astray by a coincidence. Right now, you have presented *absolutely nothing* to back up your connection - no historical evidence, no matching word for "blue moon" in another language, just a theory about a word which might have once existed - and yet you present it as "glaringly obvious" and "no need to look any further". That is exactly the kind of thinking that leads to folk etymologies spreading.